# Pretty URLs and robots.txt

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, laravel, robots.txt, pretty-urls

Let's assume we are using pretty URLs with `mod_rewrite` or something similar and have the following two routes:

- `/page`
- `/page-two`

Now we want to disallow only the first route (`/page`) to be crawled by robots.

```
# robots.txt
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page
```

> Disallow (http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html):
>
> ... For example, Disallow: /help disallows both /help.html and /help/index.html, whereas Disallow: /help/ would disallow /help/index.html but allow /help.html.

So the above `robots.txt` example is disallowing `/page-two` too, correct?

What is the correct way to get this done?

May it be the following code?

```
# robots.txt
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page/
```

Comment: `Disallow: /page` does *not* disallow `/page-two`.

Comment: Are you sure on that one (considering the quote of robotstxt.org in my question) ? :-O

Comment: @JosephSilber: You are wrong, it does. URLs don’t have a concept of files/directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Google's robots.txt specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt):

> At a group-member level, in particular for allow and disallow directives, the most specific rule based on the length of the [path] entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule. The order of precedence for rules with wildcards is undefined.

This means that it doesn't matter in what order you define them. In your case this should work:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page
Allow: /page-
```

---

To make it more clear: Every url is matched against all paths. `/page` will match `/page/123`, `/page/subdirectory/123/whateverishere.html`, `/page-123` and `/page`. The directive with the longest path that matches will be used. If both `/page` and `/page-` match, then the directive for `/page-` is used (Allow). If `/page` matches, but `/page-` doesn't match, the directive for `/page` is used (Disallow). If neither `/page` and `/page-` match, the default is assumed (Allow).

Comment: But this won't suit my needs if the second route was `/pagetwo` right? Would it be `Allow: /page*` then?

Comment: No. `/page*` will match exactly the same urls as `/page`. See the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /page-two
Disallow: /page
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. They are unlikely to make OP understand what the problem is, and are generally useless for people coming here with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> So the above robots.txt example is disallowing `/page-two` too, correct?

Correct.

> What is the correct way to get this done?

In the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), this is not possible at all.

(Note that your last example does not block `/page`, as the disallowed URLs would have to start with `/page/` (*including* the last slash).)

*Some* parsers understand `Allow` and/or wildcards, which can be used to solve your problem, but both are not part of the original specification. If you only have certain bots in mind, check their documentation to see what kind of "extensions" to robots.txt they support.

Alternatives:

- Use the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`.
- Use the `meta` element with the `robots` name (but note: `noindex` is about *indexing*, while robots.txt’s `Disallow` is about *crawling*).
- Change the URL design of your site.